# Sequelize manipulate operation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm doing a FindAll operation like the one below. I want to add URL in front of CompanyAvatar by calling it from .ENV file. Do I need to return FOR for this?

```
return CompanyModel[0].findAll({
   raw: true,
   attributes: ['companyName', 'companyAvatar']
})
```

I want this: `${'https://myserver.com/'}/companyAvatar`

Comment: You'd need to loop through the results and add the url afterwards, an even easier way would be to save the url in the db directly (If you add the url everytime you query the db for it).

Comment: I did it this way because I was trying to avoid the problem with the server or the domain. Thank you, if not, I will continue to use it like this :)